# Is 'nLockTime' equal to 'lock_time' in transaction data structure?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core

I understand how 'lock_time' field work in transaction data structure, but I also see some people talking about 'nLockTime' with similar function. So are they the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are the same. `nLockTime` is the name used in the Bitcoin Core source code (e.g. [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/3c098a8aa0780009c11b66b1a5d488a928629ebf/src/primitives/transaction.h#L184)) , whereas `locktime` or `lock_time` might be more common in JSON input/output or other pieces of software. The Bitcoin Core RPC uses `locktime` for example, and blockchain.info uses `lock_time` in its `rawtx/` endpoint